# Why my code is giving error in micopython env and not when compiled with g++

Tags: c++, esp32, micropython, esp-idf

I am having a code that runs perfectly fine when I compile it with g++ (g++ example.cpp -o myapp), but when I try to compile it using the make command for the micropython env it gives the following error.

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 0) >= this->size() (which is 0)
Aborted
```

I have provided the code below.

```
extern "C"{

#include <examplemodule.h>

}
mp_obj_t cppfunc() {
  clock_t startTime,endTime;
  startTime = clock();
  vector<vector<double> > csv_data = read_csv("A00068.csv");
  //printf("CSV_DATA:%d", csv_data);
  //printf("rows of \"%s\" file is %d.\n",argv[1], int(csv_data.size()));
  //printf("Loading the first row as ECG Series......\n");
  double *ecg_series = new double[15095976];
  int len = csv_data.at(0).size();
  //mp_printf(&mp_plat_print, "CSV_DATA:%d", csv_data.at(1));
  //get_line_from_csv(csv_data, 0, ecg_series);
  //mp_printf(&mp_plat_print, "CSV_LINE:%d\n", get_line_from_csv);
  
  double features[44];
  //get_features(ecg_series,18000,features);
  union Entry data[44];
    float result[4];
    char res[4]={'A','N','O','~'};
    int index;
  for(int i=0;i<44;i++)
  {
    data[i].missing=-1;
    data[i].fvalue=features[i];
    //printf("feature[%d]=%.8f\n",i,features[i]);
  }
  //predict_multiclass(data,0,result);
  index=(int)result[0];
  endTime = clock();
  mp_printf(&mp_plat_print, "classification result is: %C (Time cost: %.4f s)\n",res[index],(double)(endTime - startTime) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
  
  return mp_const_none;
  }
```

The line causing the error is "int len = csv_data.at(0).size();"

This is how I read the csv:

```
vector<vector<double> > read_csv(const char *filename)
{
    ifstream read_file(filename);
    vector<vector<double> > csv_data;
    std::string lineStr;
    while (getline(read_file, lineStr))
    {
        stringstream ss(lineStr);
        std::string d;
        vector<double> a_line_data;
        while (getline(ss, d, ','))
        {
            a_line_data.push_back(atof(d.c_str()));
        }
        csv_data.push_back(a_line_data);
    }
    //printf("rows of csv file:%d.\n", csv_data.size());
    return csv_data;
}
```

EDITED(I forgot to add the error)

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/projects/micropython/ports/unix $ ./micropython
MicroPython v1.16-222-g44818d1a3-dirty on 2021-08-26; linux version
Use Ctrl-D to exit, Ctrl-E for paste mode
>>> import cppexample
>>> cppexample.cppfunc()
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 0) >= this->size() (which is 0)
Aborted
```

I used [this](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/develop/cmodules.html) link to setup the micropython env, Command to reproduce the same:

cd to the micropython ports/unix/ folder
make clean
make -j4 USER_C_MODULES=../../examples/usercmodule

Comment: It looks like the CSV file was not successfully read. You should check for errors in `read_csv`.

Comment: when I use the print command to print the contents, it gives the result.

Comment: Why the micropython code shows "csv_data.size()" as 0 but when I compile it with g++ it's a 1 ?